# Evaluating $\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{x^2 y + x \sin y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - x y}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{x^2 y + x \sin y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - x y}}$$

In both iterated limits I have obtained $0$. I have also tried to get the limit in the line $y = x$, and I also get $0$. I don't know how to deal with that numerator.

I have also tried:

$$\frac{x^2 y + x \sin y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - x y}} = \frac{x (x y + \sin y)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - x y}} = \frac{x y (x + \frac{\sin y}{y})}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - x y}}$$

I would like to use something like $|x| \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $|y| \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, but the negative term in the square root doesn't allow me to use this method.

Comment: You are right, the answer is indeed 0

Comment: @Mathslover but I don't know how to prove it

Comment: Use the fact that $x^2+y^2-xy \geq |x||y|.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use
$$|x^2y|\leq|x|\cdot\frac{x^2+y^2}{2},\quad |x\sin y|\leq|xy|\leq\frac{x^2+y^2}{2},\quad x^2+y^2-xy\geq\frac{x^2+y^2}{2},$$
we have, when $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$,
$$\left|\frac{x^2y+x\sin y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-xy}}-0\right|
\leq\frac{|x^2y|+|x\sin y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-xy}}
\leq\frac{|x|\cdot\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}}
=(|x|+1)\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\to0.$$

Comment: In the very first inequality there must be $|x|$, not $|y|$.

Comment: @Aig
Thank you very much. Fixed it !

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, we have that $x^2 + y^2 - x y \ge |xy|$ then

$$\frac{|x^2 y + x \sin y|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - x y}}\le\frac{|x^2 y| + |x \sin y|}{\sqrt{|xy|}}=\sqrt{|xy|}\left(|x|+\frac{|\sin y|}{|y|}\right) \to 0$$

As noticed by Riemann, when $(x,0)\to(0,0)$ or $(0,y)\to(0,0)$ the inequality is nonsense but it is not needed because the expression is identically equal to zero.

Comment: When $(x,0)\to(0,0),x\neq0$ , your inequality  $$\frac{|x^2 y + x \sin y|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - x y}}\le\frac{|x^2 y| + |x \sin y|}{\sqrt{|xy|}}$$ is nonsense. The same to $(0,y)\to(0,0),y\neq0$.

Comment: Yes you are right but the expression is identically equal to zero in these cases. I fix it. Thanks